# arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " 09112022 "

Tags: linux, shell

```
q2(){
today_now=$(date +'%d%m%Y')
echo "$today_now"
a=$(($today_now ))
read x
b=$(($x))
if [[ "$a" -eq "$x" ]]
then 
echo "valid" 
else
echo "invalid"
fi}
```

I am getting an error

```
arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " 09112022 "
```

on the fourth line, can someone help me out?

I tired to print the todays date and the date which I provide is not equals to today then its invalid.

Comment: Leading zero. That's what's wrong. Leading zero says the number is octal, and octal numbers have no 9s. A date is not a number, don't try to treat it as such.

Comment: What do you expect `a=$(($today_now))` to do? It doesn't make `a` an integer any more than `a=$today_now` would. `dash` (which you appear to be using) doesn't *have* any data types aside from strings.

Comment: If you want to compare strings lexicographically, use `%Y%m%d` as your format instead of `%d%m%Y`.

Comment: okay,  I have changed the format and got the answer

Comment: It's not clear which shell you are using. You have tagged the question as _shell_, which meanst POSIX shell, but your code is not POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

009 and 008 are some values of octadecimal numbers so try with changinfg the format of date like from %d%m%Y to %m%d%Y

Comment: Can't months have leading zeroes ... ?

Comment: @GChuf : The shell does not know that this denotes a month. For the shell, these are integer numbers, and a leading 0 means they are taken as octal numbers. BTW, you **can** specify your months in octal, if you feel like it.